# How to catch an error thrown in an un-awaited async function inside try/ catch?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm hoping someone can suggest a better method for what I'm trying to achieve.

While performing a rather long and complicated webflow using puppeteer, occasionally an error will occur that disrupts the actions I'm trying to take on the page. There's nothing I can do about it in these situations other than return a useful error. However it doesn't happen often enough to explicitly wait and try to catch it after each step in my code.

The solution I have is:

```
async function runCode() {
    try {
         const page = browser.open(url)
          listenForError(page)
          await longWebFlow()
    } catch (err) {
      return err.message
    }
}

async function listenForError(page) {
  await page.waitForXPath(errorMessageXPath)
  throw new Error('Error found!')
}

try {
    await runCode()
} catch (err) {
console.log(err.message)
// should print('Error found')
}
```

Obviously, the unawaited `listenForError` call won't be caught in the try/catch, but I also cant `await` the call, or else I'll never get to the main part of the code.

The code works to short-circuit the process and return, since the error occurred, but how can I refactor this to catch the error message?

Comment: I don't know puppeteer, but do you need to somehow *cancel* the `waitForXPath()` call after the `longWebFlow()` is done, to avoid leaking resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you *want to wait* until either the error is thrown or the `longWebFlow()` finishes - basically doing both concurrently. That's a perfect use case for promises with [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
async function runCode() {
    const page = browser.open(url)
    await Promise.race([
        listenForError(page),
        longWebFlow(),
    ]);
}
```

You could also use `Promise.all` if you made `longWebFlow` cancel the  `listenForError` and fulfill the promise.

Either way, since you can properly `await` the promises now, the error also will be caught in the `try`/`catch`, as it should.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't `await` the `async` operation then the only other "follow up" is with callbacks like `.then()` and `.catch()`.  For example, you can catch the error here:

```
listenForError(page).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

This won't `await` the operation, it's just supplying a callback for whenever that operation fails at whatever point in the future.

Comment: gotcha -- the only way I can think to make that work is to wrap the whole thing in a Promise, which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @CameronSima: What needs to be wrapped in a `Promise`?  The `listenForError` function already returns a `Promise`, this is just appending a callback to that `Promise`.

Comment: the whole code block. The purpose is to get the error message out of this function call and back to the caller, not to console.log it

Comment: @CameronSima: You don't *have to* log it to the console, you can do whatever you like with the error in the callback function.  `console.log` is just a simple illustration of "doing something with the result".  What are you trying to do with the result that you otherwise can't?

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question wasn't really that clear. Updated the question